# In how many and which ways can a logic be non-classical? Are there systems for organizing them?

Tags: logic, reference-request, non-classical-logic

I asked on MathSE [What are the various respects under which a logic can deviate from classical logic, thus being “ non-classical”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903145/what-are-the-various-respects-under-which-a-logic-can-deviate-from-classical-log) and received one short answer. So, I'm interested in responses from Philosophy SE, too.

**In what ways can a logic deviate from classical logic?** I think one can find rather easily a list (though maybe incomplete) of non-classical logics. But it seems more difficult to find a presentation of the field that exhibits in a systematic fashion under which respects a logic can be non-classical.

The aspects I can think of are the following:

> 1. Type of objects over which quantifiers range --> first-order/ second-order logic
> 2. Validity of "ex falso" or not  --> paraconsistent logics
> 3. Use of modal operators, or not --> modal logics
> 4. Finite or infinite number of premises --> compactness maybe?

There is an attempt at such a presentation in Theodore Sider's book [Logic For Philosophy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Logic_for_Philosophy/9UUdAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=theodore%20logic%20for%20philosophy), but I'd be much interested in other references.

Note: I'm not asking for an absolutely complete list of points of departure from classical logic; I suppose it would be too long. Rather, what interests me is the systematicity of the presentation.

Comment: Edited to avoid the "duplicate objection".

Comment: Your list strangely omits the tremendously important intuitionistic logics, which are characterized by the omission of DNE (double negation elimination, ¬¬p→p) and related matters.

Answer (score 11):

Some of these might plausibly be called extensions of classical logic rather than non-classical in the strict sense, but I'll take your question as a broad one about logics that progress beyond elementary classical first order predicate logic. It is not exhaustive.

**Valency**: [Bivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_logic). [Multivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic). Not n-valent for any n. [Fuzzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic). [Probabilistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_logic). [Subjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_logic).

**Order**: [First-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). [Second-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic). [Higher-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic).

**Domain**: [Free logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic) that permit [quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/) over non-existent objects, or allow empty domains.

**Variables**: [Typeless vs. typed/many-sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic).  [Dependence logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dependence/). [Independence-friendly logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence-friendly_logic).

**Quantification**: [Generalised quantifiers.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/) Branching quantifiers. [Plural quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/). [Objectual vs. substitutional](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#SubQua). Logics without quantified variables ([combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic))

**Rules of implication**:

- no [LEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) ([intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic))
- no [explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) ([paraconsistent logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic))
- no (or restricted) disjunction introduction ([relevance logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/))
- no (or restricted) LNC ([dialethic logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/))
- restricted distributivity ([quantum logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/))
- no (or restricted) structural rules ([substructural logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/), [bunched logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunched_logic), [noncommutative logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_logic))
- no idempotency of entailment ([linear logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/), [affine logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_logic))
- restricted [law of identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_identity) (non-reflexive logic, [Schrödinger logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_logic))
- no monotonicity of entailment ([non-monotonic logics, default logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-nonmonotonic/))
- restricted transitivity of entailment ([core logic](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Core_Logic/Q2IwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en))
- connexivity of conditionals ([connexive logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-connexive/))

[Modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic): De dicto and de re. [Quantified modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#QuaModLog). [Intensional logics.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intensional/) Hyperintensional logics. [Possible world semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-worlds/).

- [alethic (necessary truth)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog)
- [doxastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic), [provability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/)
- [epistemic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/)
- [deontic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/)
- interrogatory
- [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_logic)
- [action](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-action/)
- [justification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/)
- etc.

[Temporal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/).

[Conditional logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-conditionals/). [Counterfactuals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/counterfactuals/). [Causal calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-models/).

[Infinitary logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic).

[Multiple conclusion logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-conclusion_logic).

The group under 'rules of implication' are strictly non-classical, as would be any non-bivalent logic. Modal and temporal logics are usually extensions of classical logic, though one could have a modal intuitionistic logic, for example. Others might be non-classical or not depending on how they are set up.

Comment: Aren't provability logics and doxastic logics the same thing just with a slightly different semantic interpretation?

Comment: This answer is good, but I think it could be improved if you split into things that are extensions of classical logic, v.s. things that do have all the laws of classical logic. I know you mentioned the distinction, but structuring the answer based on that could be helpful.