# Is this outline typical of the organization of academic analytic philosophy?

Tags: terminology, metaphilosophy, analytic-philosophy, classification, branches

After doing some research I came up with the following classification of analytic philosophy. Do certain branches overlap or worse, are there any inclusions that I have missed?

- [Axiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology)

  - [Æsthetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetics)

    - [Philosophy of beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty)
    - [Philosophy of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art)
  - [Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics)
- [Epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology)

  - [Social epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_epistemology)
  - [Philosophy of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science)

    - Philosophy of formal sciences
    - Philosophy of natural sciences
    - Philosophy of social sciences
    - [Metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy)
- [Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/)

  - [Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality)
  - [Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/)
  - [Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)
  - [Philosophy of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind)
- [Philosophy of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_information)

  - [Semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics)

    - [Philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language)
- [Social philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_philosophy)

  - [Philosophy of culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_culture)

    - [Philosophy of technology](http://n)
  - [Political philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy)

I do consider logic as distinct from philosophy but rather part of formal sciences. So philosophy of logic would be under philosophy of science.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: I've gone back and added links, and took a stab at your hierarchy. I think the question itself, which is largely metaphilosophical is a good one for our knowledge base. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: - Added some European schools. No idea what the organization is like there.

Comment: I originally wanted to classify the fields of study not the answers brought by specific schools, but thanks

Comment: In the [Continental tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_philosophy) philosophy is conducted holistically, so not so much by fields of studies, and you'd be remiss if you're interested in philosophy generally to disregard. If you that's the case, you might want to adjust your question to specify you're talking about within the [analytic school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy).

Comment: I've also moved the current tree to my answer, so free to rearrange anyway you'd like :D!

Comment: I edited the question accordingly!

Comment: PhilPapers has a much more detailed [taxonomy](https://philpapers.org/utils/struct.pl) that you can peruse.

Comment: I already looked at it but for many reasons it is not satisfactory for me (Philosophical Traditions, History of Western Philosophy, Mathematics… are not relevant for example)

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

To be technical, concepts are related by webs rather than hierarchies, so any attempt to map a [network to a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy) is [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology), however, what you have given seems to be largely consistent with how [philosophy is traditionally organized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetics).

### Long Answer

Your schema seems rather non-controversial, however, some tweaking (I edited the OP) might be in order. Since [psychologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty), language is generally accepted as a product of the mind. For instance, the philosophy of linguistics and language are interrelated. I'm aware of no analytic philosopher who rejects modern linguistics and but conducts philosophy of language in its absence. If you wanted, you might want to add the philosophies of the five fundamental sciences that are taught extensively in secondary and higher education: philosophies of physics, chemistry, biology, psychology, and sociology. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art) also lists modality as a topic of metaphysics, but once again, ontology, modality, and epistemology aren't crisp boundaries but rather interplay with each other, so SEP has an article on the [epistemology of modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics). For most analytical philosophers, logic and fallacy, [rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-ethics), and [argumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_ethics) are often seen as language usage where the [formal logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_ethics) are [syntactical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) in nature and [informal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_ethics) is [semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_epistemology) and generally concerned with [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science). See the SE Philosophy Q&A [In how many and which ways can a logic be non-classical? Are there systems for organizing them?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77449/in-how-many-and-which-ways-can-a-logic-be-non-classical-are-there-systems-for-o) for more information on types of non-classical logics if you're interested in lists. Lastly, there are philosophers who are interested in the nature of philosophy itself which is studied in [metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_space_and_time). You'll find that besides the analytic and continental traditions, there are [theological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_motion), [Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_physics), [Chinese](http://h), and other traditions in and outside of Anglo-America and Continental Europe. Lastly, what comes to mind is the [philosophy of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_biology) which is a much more modern philosophy that tries to take [ICT principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_psychology) and ensure they're consistent with traditional philosophical thinking. Central to this philosophy are the [information sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_social_science) which have become all the rage in computer science departments.

This is what I'd propose:

- [Metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy)
- [Axiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology)

  - [Æsthetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetics)

    - [Philosophy of beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty)
    - [Philosophy of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art)
  - [Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics)

    - [Meta-ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-ethics)
    - [Normative ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_ethics)
    - [Applied ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_ethics)
- [Epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology)

  - [Social epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_epistemology)
  - [Philosophy of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science)

    - [Philosophy of space and time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_space_and_time)
    - [Philosophy of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_motion)
    - [Philosophy of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_physics)
    - [Philosophy of chemistry](http://h)
    - [Philosophy of biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_biology)
    - [Philosophy of psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_psychology)
    - [Philosophy of sociology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_social_science)
- [Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/)

  - [Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality)
  - [Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/)
  - [Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)
  - [Philosophy of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind)

    - [Philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language)

      - [Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic)
      - [Rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric)
      - [Argumentation Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentation_theory)
    - [Philosophy of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics)
- [Social philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_philosophy)

  - [Philosophy of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_information)
  - [Philosophy of technology](http://n)
  - [Philosophy of culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_culture)
  - [Political philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy)
  - [Philosophy of economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_and_economics)
- [Semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics)
- [Phenomenology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenology_(philosophy))
- [Critical Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_theory)
- [Structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will consider your advices. I considered metaphilosophy, philosophy of physics… as parts of philosophy of science but a distinction has to be made with the study of the scientific method itslef. Anyway thank you ahain

Comment: Could you explain why social philosophy could not be considered part of the axiology since political philosophy is about what makes a system of government legitimate (which could be considered a value)?

Comment: And finally, I find it a bit problematic to put the theories of reference in philosophy of language as a sub-part of philosophy of mind.

Comment: You can rearrange as you see fit. Language is a product of the mind. No mind, no language. Theories of reference are generally linguistic.

Comment: I will do more research about it then, thank you very much

Comment: Also, so you're clear, ALL language is value-laden, because language is a social practice of convention...

Comment: I just added semiotics which is continental...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117104/discussion-between-j-d-and-blincer).

Answer (score 1):

Analytic philosophy focusses on these key areas:

- language & logic
- metaphysics
- epistemology

Your classification includes a number of non-analytic topics including:

axiology, social epistemology, culture, political philosophy

see 'Analytic Philosophy: An Anthology' ed. Martinich and Sosa