# Is there any logic where P->P is not a wff

Tags: logic

Basically the title. Are non reflexive logics one such logical system?

Comment: It is a well-formed formula of propositional logic. The "conditional" operator is a binary connective that takes two formulas as input: that's all.

Comment: Not a wff or just not a propositional tautology?

Comment: If you mean a system of logic in which A → A is not a theorem of the logic, then yes there are a few. One such is the logic S, which is part of the family of relevance logics. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/#SysRelLog

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate question, but it would have an *answer* that partly duplicated [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/96752/40843).

Comment: It is not a wff in syllogistic logic which has no sentential operators.

Comment: Just curious, re this question, it got me wondering: would _P-->P_ work in linear logic, or would you need _!P-->P_ to account for its resource awareness?

Answer (score 1):

If P → P means that P implies P, then it is true.

If you assume for whatever reason that it is not, then you are just being illogical.

Another way to say this is that any expression "P → P" which is not true does not refer to the implication P implies P.

Comment: It would be a wtf instead (without truth formula).